# What is the selector field for when validating DKIM records?

Tags: email, dkim

I am trying to use http://dkimcore.org/tools/ to validate my DKIM records.  I am using http://elasticemail.com to send email from my site and I need to set these text records up on my DNS.  I don't know what the selector field is for to test my inputs on my DNS?